# How to split json data in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

How to split json data  in PowerApps

I have a json format text
{"ID":"1","name":"yashpal"}
and I need to split the data and assign 1 to textbox1 and Yashpal to textbox2

Answer (score 1):

Power Apps currently does not have a general JSON parsing mechanism, but if you know that the text you have will always have the same format, and the 'name' property cannot have double quotes (`"`), then you can use a regular expression to extract the values, something along the lines of

```
With(
    Match(
        <<the json text>>,
        "\""ID\"":\""(?<id>[^\""]+)\"",\""name\"":\""(?<name>[^\""]+)\"""), 
    UpdateContext({defaultId: id, defaultName: name}))
```

And you can use the variables `defaultId` and `defaultName` as the Default property of 'textbox1' and 'textbox2', respectively.